# PHP: Call to undefined function: simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, xml, function, curl

I am implementing facebook count function using cron file. In which cron runs every 10 minutes and counts the total likes of a page.

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $source_url =$cars[$i];
    $rest_url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=".urlencode($source_url);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$rest_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $message=stripslashes($content);
    $xml_record = simplexml_load_string($message);
    $fb_like_count = $xml_record->link_stat->like_count;
    echo "".$fb_like_count;
    mail("abc@gmail.com","hi".$fb_like_count,$message);
}
```

But I am geting undefined call function error.

Comment: Do you have `php-xml` module installed and enabled?

Answer (score 170):

For PHP 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 the procedure is follows. Since PHP 7 is not in the official Ubuntu PPAs you likely installed it through Ondřej Surý's PPA (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php). Go to /etc/php/7.0/fpm and edit php.ini, uncomment to following line:

```
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
```

Then simply install php7.0-xml:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

And restart PHP:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

And restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you are on a later Ubuntu version where PHP 7 is included, the procedure is most likely the same as well (except adding any 3rd party repository).

Comment: Just fyi you don't need to uncomment extension=php_xmlrpc.dll on Ubuntu as that is a windows extension just do the second step and it will work

Comment: i followed the same : still i get Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in /var/www/html/magento1901/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

Comment: I had received a unrecognized service error. I just restarted apache2 and this fixed this issue. Thaks for the help find this line in PHP.ini

Comment: yep, this worked, and I was able to skip the first step as @wmfrancia stated.

Comment: I tried the same but didn't work for me. From error log  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php

Comment: for php5.6 I uncommented the line as in answer in /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini, helped me

Comment: I just did "sudo apt install php-xml", no need for other steps

Answer (score 60):

If the XML module is not installed, install it.

Current version 5.6 on ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

> And don't forget to run sudo service apache2 restart command after it

*Zulhilmi Zainudi*

Comment: You can just do "sudo apt install php-xml" and it will get the correct version for you.

Comment: And don't forget to run `sudo service apache2 restart` command after it

Answer (score 13):

I also faced this issue. My Operating system is **Ubuntu 18.04** and my PHP version is **PHP 7.2**.

**Here's how I solved it:**

Install Simplexml on your Ubuntu Server:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-simplexml
```

Restart Apache Server

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 8):

I think it can be something like in this Post:
[Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found on puphpet PHP 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223926/class-simplexmlelement-not-found-on-puphpet-php-5-6)
So maybe you could install/activate

```
php-xml or php-simplexml
```

Do not forget to activate the libraries in the **php.ini** file. (like the top [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36407094/7796430))

Comment: Also try this [link](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?191658-RESOLVED-Fatal-error-Call-to-undefined-function-simplexml_load_file()&s=2a5f7a91ae737417b735ec83fbf17295&p=932942#post932942)

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you have php-xml module installed and enabled in `php.ini`.

You can also change response format to json which is easier to handle. In that case you have to only add `&format=json` to url query string.

```
$rest_url = "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=".urlencode($source_url);
```

And then use `json_decode()` to retrieve data in your script:

```
$result = json_decode($content, true);
$fb_like_count = $result['like_count'];
```

Comment: i have modified my terminal php version then it is working fine

Answer (score 6):

For Nginx (without apache) and PHP 7.2, installing php7.2-xml wasn't enough. Had to install php7.2-simplexml package to get it to work

So the commands for debian/ubuntu, update packages and install both packages

```
apt update
apt install php7.2-xml php7.2-simplexml
```

And restart both Nginx and php

```
systemctl restart nginx php7.2-fpm
```

Answer (score 4):

To fix this error on *Centos 7*:

1. Install PHP extension:

   ```
   sudo yum install php-xml
   ```
2. Restart your web server. In my case it's *php-fpm*:

   ```
   sudo service php-fpm restart
   ```

Comment: I'd forgotten all about php-fpm. Thank you!!!