# Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, magento, simplexml, magento-1.9

Call to undefined function `simplexml_load_string()`

I am getting this error on all the sites located on our server. Everything was working correctly until today and all of sudden this error poped up.

I have checked Simplexml and it is already installed on the server. Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in
>   .../lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

Comment: Same thing happened to me, today also. Yesterday everything was fine.

Comment: Some more troubleshooting is showing the following:
When i go in the command line and enter php -m i can see SimpleXML in the list. However if I create a file on my server, and try extension_loaded("SimpleXML") it returns false

Comment: This is some XML file error. Please check the resend changed XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today. I tried to check whether extension is loaded and I was getting true (from command line) Then I found that I was using multiple php versions and the site in question was using php5.4 which for some reason was failing for simplexml

Since I am in a cPanel/WHM environment I ran

```
yum install ea-php54-php-simplexml
```

which fixed the issue. This is for EasyApache4. Perhaps you can just update simplexml sepending on your flavour of linux.

Comment: When I tried yum install ea-php-70-php-simplexml it says: Package ea-php70-php-xml-7.0.19-3.3.1.cpanel.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
Any thoughts? Also any idea why so many people have the same problem the same day?

Comment: is it possible that you are not using php 7 for this specific site? cPanel and php56+ allows for multiple php installations together. My issue was that the site in question was using php 5.4 so I needed to do yum install ea-php54.... etc As per the question of the same day problem, I guess it has to do with cPanel updates

Comment: I only have php 7 enabled for the entire server and no other version active

Answer (score 0):

Installing latest extension resolved the issue.

yum install ea-php56-php-simplexml

Answer (score 0):

It may be late, but for future readres.
I had almost the same issue, the problem was that, in console, the `php.ini` file path was different from the `php.ini` path for web pages that served from apache.

Since you said with `php -m i` you can see SimpleXML. maybe you need to edit different ini file.
You can create a php file with content of `<?php phpinfo();` and chack `Loaded Configuration File` value to make sure if you are editing the right file.

if you need to install SimpleXML [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206186/php-call-to-undefined-function-simplexml-load-string).