# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php:510

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm getting this error. Can you please help me understand why it is coming and what does it mean. I did not change any code. It is running on PHP 7.1 and Operating system is Linux.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: SourceGuardian: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20160303
PHP    compiled with module API=20170718
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function 
simplexml_load_string() in public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php:510
Stack trace:
#0 /home3/ramesqj3/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(498): 
Varien_Simplexml_Config->loadString('<?xml version="...', 
'Mage_Core_Model...') 
#1/home3/ramesqj3/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(277): 
Varien_Simplexml_Config->loadFile('/home3/ramesqj3...')
#2 /home3/ramesqj3/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(391): 
Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadBase()
#3 /home3/ramesqj3/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): 
Mage_Core_Model_App->_initBaseConfig()
#4 /home3/ramesqj3/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): 
Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
#5 /home3/ramesqj3/public_html/app/Mage.php(686): Mage_Core_Model_App- 
>run(Array)
#6 /home3/ramesqj3/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
thrown in  public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206186/call-to-undefined-function-simplexml-load-string

Comment: Do mention your OS, Php version you are on and also check if you have `php-xml` installed in your system.